# How to figure out primary/secondary IDE channel via sysfs (if possible)

Tags: linux, devices, sata, sysfs, pata

Though I've got quite a good basic understanding of `sysfs` meanwhile, there are still things I cannot solve on my own.

For a starter, I'd like to figure out *via `sysfs`* (later by scripting of course) which channel a block device (HDD, DVD...) is connected to.

The funny thing about it is that it is possible for me how to figure out **master or slave**! There is an internal ID deeply rooted in the `sysfs` tree which gives this away: so `9:0:1` will mean that the device is connected to a (primary OR secondary) **slave** channel. (master when last digit 0; slave when last digit is 1)
OK, but this will still not tell me whether it's the primary or secondary channel.

While doing some research about this, I found a **Linux 2.6**-related post in LKML: https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/3/25/20 revealing a sample path like `../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/ide0/0.0/`.

Well this is EXACTLY what I need!
Unfortunately though, the `ideX` is nowhere to find in `sysfs` as of Linux 3.x. Maybe it was removed for good in kernel version 3?

Answer (score 0):

Things have been reorganised.

Now, ATA devices (old IDE PATA — parallel — and newer SATA — serial) are all under the `/sys/devices/pcixxxx:xx/xxxx:xx:xx.x/atax` path (where `x` represents numbers), for instance `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/ata1/link1` for the first device on the first controller.

Comment: OK, thanks, but what if it *is* a PATA controller, with all __but__ the primary slave channel connected to a device? Won't `link` just be numbered `link1`, `link2`, `link3` anyway? I would not think that there will be a gap (as ..1, ..3, ..4).